# What is alternative hashing for String keys in Java 8?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hash, hashcode

Java 8 is providing alternative hashing for String keys to improve performance when a large number of key hash code collisions are encountered. Can anybody explain what is that and how it will work?

Comment: +1 This could be used to avoid denial of service attacks.

Comment: Thanks i will keep this in mind

Comment: @PeterLawrey Are you referring to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=750533) or something else when you mention DoS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this email](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.core-libs.devel/10361) of `core-lib-devs@openjkd`:

> - A new interface Hashable32 is introduced.
> - Hashable32 provides a method hash32()
> - String implements Hashable32 and hash32() method
> - HashMap et al recognize String and invoke hash32() rather than hashCode()

The revisions of the code:

- Murmur3 : https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3
- althashing "7" webrev :
  http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mduigou/althashing7/8/webrev/
- althashing "8" webrev :
  http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mduigou/althashing8/8/webrev/

Comment: From what I can tell, the biggest flaws with the old hashing algorithm were that it sometimes returned zero for long strings, and that specifying a particular implementation precluded the possibility of having the VM implement a "hash-string" function which was designed for optimal performance on that particular machine (e.g. a 64-bit machine might use a function which operates on groups of 8 bytes and then munges the result down to 32 bits).  I wonder how much code really relies upon the exact values of the old string hash, and how hard it would be to allow a 'compatibility workaround'?

Answer (score 10):

To bring more relevance to this question, the alternative hashing has been removed from JDK 8. Check out :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes8.html

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180

It is interesting to note that once the number of items in a hash bucket grows beyond a certain threshold, that bucket will switch from using a linked list of entries to a balanced tree.

The hash(Object key) function in the HashMap has been revised to follows with no special treatment to String objects:

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that the shift to MurmurHash3 will not prevent DoS attacks:
http://emboss.github.com/blog/2012/12/14/breaking-murmur-hash-flooding-dos-reloaded/